# Is it possible to run ColdFusion 9 alongside ColdFusion 11?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

I am currently having problems about the PDF file that a cfdocument tag generates. Our main branch of the company is using CF9, and my local machine is using CF11. When they pull my git branches for testing, the PDF file layouts with the HTML varied a lot (e.g. CF9 table cells auto wrap texts, a 1 pixel border in CF11 is thicker than a 1 pixel border in CF9). I'm not sure if this is what it is supposed to be but I'd really like to know if it is safe to run CF9 and CF11 together or is it even possible? Thanks!

Update: An error occured while installing CF9.

```
ZeroGur: Windows DLL failed to load
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at ZeroGa4.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
```

Comment: Probably, if you get all of the connections right (proper version of java for each etc) and have the resources, then configure your webserver to route to the correct version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to ensure that the code will work with a certain version of ColdFusion is to code and test on the same version of ColdFusion. You can install both CF9 and CF11 on your local machine. While working on this particular project, just start the CF9 server.

Comment: How should I go about specifically starting the CF9 service and not the CF11? Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin, On windows, you can go to Control Panel > Administrative tools > Services. Then find appropriate CF application server service. You can start and stop this service by right clicking and selecting start/stop option. So When you want to use CF9 server, you should start ColdFusion 9 Application Server.

Comment: @Kevin, I am not sure about how to do it on Mac And Linux. But there may be something similar to this on respective Os'es.

Comment: CF9 (and I think 10) will not install on Windows 8 or Server 2012, it is missing expected files. Sounds like you would be better off using some virtual machines to replicate your production environment.

Comment: @Kevin, check out these links, http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/02/coldfusion-9-on-windows-8.html and
http://cfsimplicity.com/76/installing-coldfusion-9-on-windows-8

Comment: Thanks! Reading them now.